# solving the first 5 elements of a given recursion sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, recursion

**Given:**

The sequence $(u_{n})$ with
$u_{n+2}=4 \cdot u_{n+1}-u_{n}$

and  $u_{4}=194$

with $u_{1}<u_{2}$
, $u_{i} \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$

**To solve:**
$u_{1},u_{2},u_{3},u_{5}$

I tried solving it by replacing $u_{3}$ in $u_{4}= 4u_{3} - u_{2}$ with $4u_{2} - u_{1}$

Like this I got $194 = 15u_{2} - 4u_{1}$

But it doesn't really get me anywhere. I tried the same logic till $u_{5}$, but no success. This way I thought I would get an equation somehow to solve for $u_{1}$.

I think I'm overlooking something or not even getting close.

Comment: I think if you just give $n$ different values, you will get a set of equations. Then you plug in $n_4$ and the others should be solvable from there. So just try $n=3$ ... Do you know $u_0$?

Comment: $u_{0}$ is not given, but it doesn't get me anywhere if i just plug in different values, i always end up with one element I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now,
$$u_2=\frac{4u_1+194}{15}>u_1,$$ which gives
$$1\leq u_1\leq17$$ and only $u_1=4$ is valid.

Can you end it now?

Comment: Yeah I definitely overlooked the fact that $u_{i} \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ and its importance, I didn't exactly know how I could use it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: You are welcome @Zeke